# Hello, help with CODE servo mechanism and DS1307

Tags: servo, time

I am trying to make a auto feeder for birds!,
I can't setup my code, the aim is to move servo when the certain time comes,
My commend if doesnt work, what else commend can I use?

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <Servo.h>

RTC_DS1307 RTC;
Servo myservo;
 
void setup () {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin();
    RTC.begin();
    myservo.attach(9);
    myservo.write(45);

  if (! RTC.isrunning()) {
   Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    
  RTC.adjust(DateTime(2017,05,18,11,10,0)); 
  }
}

void loop () {
    DateTime now = RTC.now();
Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
 Serial.print('/');
 Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
 Serial.print('/');
 Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
 Serial.print(" (");
 Serial.print(") ");
 Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
 Serial.print(':');
 Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
 Serial.print(':');
 Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print(" since midnight 1/1/1970 = ");
 Serial.print(now.unixtime());
 Serial.print("s = ");
 Serial.print(now.unixtime() / 86400L);
 Serial.println("d");
 
    if ( now.hour()== 10 && now.minute() == 18){
      Serial.print('a');   
  
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `my code doesnt work` is meaningless ... something like `my code does xyz, and i would like it to do abc123` has a meaning

Comment: also, please indent your code properly ... it shows the fliw of the code, like paragraphs in a book ... it is indented properly in first half of setup(), and then it gets messy ... the first line of loop() is indented properly and then all the serial.print statements are badly indented ... my guess is that you added the badly formatted code